# where does Apache Flume logs its error messages?

Tags: apache, flume

I'm new to Apache flume, Just I want to know, where does Apacheflume  logs its error messages and metadata information.
I searched apche flume directory for captured error logs, but I did'nt see any floder with the name log.

Could anyone help me on this, how to configure logs in apache flume.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flume logs are in */var/log/flume-ng*. This location is specified in logging configuration file */etc/flume-ng/conf/log4j.properties*.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry,

But I'm not seeing the directory which you specified here, Currently I'm using Apache Flume1.3.1, it's not having the flume-ng folder. please do let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: I personally recommend to install Flume from Cloudera's distribution (1 - http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_4_4.html, 2 - http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera-content/cloudera-docs/CDH4/latest/CDH4-Installation-Guide/cdh4ig_topic_12_4.html) and run Flume as service - then it works out of the box and logs are in standard place. However, with Apache's binaries there still should be log4j.properties file in "conf" directory. Then you run "flume-ng agent -c conf ...". See http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html.

Answer (score 1):

Dmitry is right, the log file location is specified in `FLUME_HOME/conf/log4j.properties`.

I just wanted to add that, in Apache Flume 1.5, the default log location is:

```
FLUME_HOME/logs/flume.log
```

The log file may not be generated in case Flume initialization failed - this usually means that Flume couldn't find Java, configuration files, etc.